# Captured image on ImageView was disappeared when the phone is in Landscape mode why?

Tags: android

I am using relative Layout for my project.

Xml code:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/next"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageview" />
```

Comment: Add `android:configChanges="screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"` in your activity tag of manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch your phone from portrait to landscape, the activity is recreated and onCreate is recalled, so you have to save the state of your activity, or in your case your uri and reset when orientation changed.

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest ,for respective activity apply configChanges:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|orientation|screenSize">
```

This may help you solving your issue.